# Http 500 in IIS Log when i throw a c# exception

Tags: c#, exception, iis, logging

Is there any possibility to throw an exception in the code of a web application which would not cause error 500 in the IIS logs?

Comment: You're throwing an uncaught exception. This means something has gone wrong. What do you want to happen instead?

Comment: Exceptions should be logged, so the problems that caused them could be fixed

Comment: so all exception types logs 500 in server logs ?

Answer (score 0):

500 means internal server error, i.e. your application have failed.

I'm guessing that you are asking for some sort of indication when the ***client*** have done something wrong.

For MVC 5.x there is an `HttpException` which can be used to return other error codes. *(500 is returned for all exceptions but `HttpException`)*

However! Exceptions are application failures. Your application does not fail just because the client sent something invalid.

Instead, you should send back a `HttpResponse` with the correct HTTP code. For MVC applications you can use the `HttpStatusCodeResult` in the controller.